# THREE.Line with blur

Tags: three.js

Is there any options for Line with blur or others filters?

I use alternative for Line with `THREE.Plane` with texture but imitate moving with position vector and `lookAt` is not simple as dynamic line with `vertices[0]` a `vertices[1]`.

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can use postprocessing, as in http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/webgl_lines_colors.html. There are other examples with blur filters, too.

Answer (score 2):

The Line object using the WebGLRenderer does not have many options. Using the CanvasRenderer or SVG renderer I believe you can do more with it. For instance, most WebGL implementations (Chrome in Windows) only support a maximum line width of 1, so you cannot even change the width. If you switch to the CanavsRenderer you can set it with the 'lineWidth' option. However, I do not know if it is possible to blur the line with a simple option like this.

If you are wanting to use the WebGLRenderer, your best bet is to look up info on GLSL and writing custom shaders. Then check out this example on how to write a custom shader for the Line object. **[This example](http://alteredqualia.com/three/examples/webgl_custom_attributes_lines.html)** seems to do just this very well. I'm sure it could be adapted to do what you are aiming for.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I am newbie in GLSL and i don't know how rewrite shaders for glow line.  Have you any examples (without webgl_atributes_lines ;]) ?.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `THREE.Ribbon` as I did. Basically, the points in `Ribbon.geometry` are rendered as quads, as a ribbon would. For example, having the points

```
Ribbon.geometry=[
new THREE.Vertex3(1,0,0),
new THREE.Vertex3(-1,0,0),
new THREE.Vertex3(1,0,10),
new THREE.Vertex3(-1,0,10)
]
```

would render a thin strip from the origin outwards on the z axis. You can use `Ribbon.geometry.colors` to add colors to each vertex. Ranging from white to black, combined with the Ribbon's material, `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial` having `THREE.AdditiveBlending` and `THREE.DoubleSide`, you can change the geometry's vertices in real time and have a transparent fading effect! Don't forget to populate the vertex list to a predefined amount when initializing, because you can't add any more after it is initialized! You could combine with a bloom filter as well.